# Module Dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to work with a project which has two modules, say `M1` and `M2`. `M1` should have `M2` as a dependency. I've added a class `Test` to `M2` which I want to access from `M1`.

I'm working with Android Studio 0.3.2. Whatever I try (reimporting project, sync gradle files, ..), I cannot access the `Test` class from `M1`: `Cannot resolve symbol 'Test'`.

**Folder structure:**

```
- root
    - M1
        - src
        - build.gradle
        - ...
    - M2
        - src
        - build.gradle
        - ...
    - build.gradle
    - settings.gradle
    - ...
```

**root/settings.gradle:**

```
include ':M1', ':M2'
```

**root/build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
```

**root/M1/build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':M2')
}
```

**root/M2/build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

Running `gradlew compileDebug` gives:

```
root\M1\src\main\java\com\mypackage\m1\MainActivity.java:28: error: package com.mypackage.m2 does not exist
    com.mypackage.m2.Test test;
                    ^
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Weird... I have a similar config, and it's working fine. So, obvious questions: when you open `MainActivity` in Android Studio, do you see the wavy-red-thing under `com.mypackage.m2`? Does the class `Test` actually exists? Did you import the package? Have you tried to run `gradlew clean build`?

Comment: The word `Test` in `com.mypackage.m2.Test test;` is red. Autocomplete does not find the package `m2`. It does exist in the module `M2`. `import com.mypackage.m2.*;` results in `unused import statement` (no error though). I've tried running gradlew clean build just now, no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your module apply the android application plugin with

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

If M1 is to depend on M2, M2 must be a library project, and its gradle file should say

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```